# How to get current location(GPS) after click on radio button in my android app?

Tags: android

i have taken one radio button as GPS.
now i want to show my current location when i clicked on that radio button..
how to achieve it?
please give me some sample code for the same...

Thanks in Advance---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code in radiobutton onclick event.....

```
        Location location;
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(
                        "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                        location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
                Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.new3pin);
                HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(
                        drawable, LbsGeocodingActivity.this);
            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "No Location Found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

second HelloItemizedOverlay.java class..

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mOverlays.size();
    }


    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have pasted the sample code [Here](http://pastebin.com/FqB1nLuL)

Crete one interface to notify when location is obtained.. put code in OnClick event(or onSelected) of your Radio button

`LocProvider locProvider = LocProvider.getInstance();
                locProvider.init(this);
                locProvider.initializeLocationSearch();
                locProvider.setLocationCallbackListener(<crete ownlistener and assign here>);`